# Setting JQuery Animate parameters with a variable

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-animate

I am trying to use a variable to set the CSS parameters to be changed in a JQuery Animate function.    I understand it needs to be passed an object, but it still doesn't seem to work.  All elements are absolutely positioned.

**CODE:**

```
var parameters = JSON.stringify("top:'-100'");
$("#test-element").animate(parameters,1000);
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/37tLw/1/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` doesn't create an object, it creates a JSON string from an object?

Try :

```
var parameters = {top: "-100"}; // <--- actual object ?
$("#test-element").animate(parameters,1000);
```

or if for some reason it just has to be JSON:

```
var parameters = JSON.parse('{"top":"-100"}');
$("#test-element").animate(parameters,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

i have updated your fiddle

`jsFiddle` - http://jsfiddle.net/37tLw/2/